# Flat module Angular

Tags: angular, module

We have a big Angular 8 application and we are going to split it into modules.

This means creating directory for each module and moving corresponding components there. It also involves creation of one 'shared' module. This 'moving things overhead' means a lot of work and might be a bit error prone. Also if we decide in the future to move one component between modules it costs us some overhead.

On the other hand I like the idea to have flat modules while keeping current application directory structure and only specifying in each module which components it contains.

The question is whether there are any drowbacks of having flat modules I should be aware of.

Comment: Good time to barrel load if you don't already.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with IntelliJ and Visual Studio Code with modules located in directories. Now and then I moved components around and I have been easy to follow the compile errors. Most of the times it has behaved as in Java or .NET development.